# When is the sum of three reduced rationals equal to an integer

Tags: congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem, exponential-sum, congruence-relations

When is the sum of three reduced rationals equal to an integer?

This may be a duplicate of [Question 1550437](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550437/when-is-a-finite-sum-of-rational-numbers-an-integer) but even if it is, there is no answer associated with this other question.

Given three moduli, $m1$, $m2$, and $m3$, not necessarily distinct or coprime, but $m_i > 1$ $\forall m_i$, when does the sum of rationals:
\begin{equation}
\left(
  \frac{r_1}{m_1}
+ \frac{r_2}{m_2}
+ \frac{r_3}{m_3}
\right)
\end{equation}
admit integer solutions? The remainders, $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$, are all coprime to the corresponding modulus;
i.e. $(r_1, m_1) = (r_2, m_2) = (r_3, m_3) = 1$.
The rationals in the sum are in reduced form: i.e.
$r_i < m_i$ $\forall r_i$

The question can be restated for what constellation of modulii do coprime remainders exists such that:
\begin{equation}
\left(
  \frac{r_1}{m_1}
+ \frac{r_2}{m_2}
+ \frac{r_3}{m_3}
\right)
\in
\mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
is true for at least one constellation of remainders?

I have found some solutions:
\begin{align}
\left( m_1, m2 \right) = \left( m_1, m3 \right) = \left( m_2, m3 \right) = 1
&\implies
\nexists r_1, r_2, r_3
\text{ $\mid$ }
\left(
  \frac{r_1}{m_1}
+ \frac{r_2}{m_2}
+ \frac{r_3}{m_3}
\right) 
\in
\mathbb{Z}
\\
\left( m_1, m2 \right) = 1 \text{ and } m_3 \ne m_1 m_2
&\implies
\nexists r_1, r_2, r_3
\text{ $\mid$ }
\left(
  \frac{r_1}{m_1}
+ \frac{r_2}{m_2}
+ \frac{r_3}{m_3}
\right) 
\in
\mathbb{Z}
\\
\left( m_1, m2 \right) = 1 \text{ and } m_3 = m_1 m_2
&\implies
\exists r_1, r_2, r_3
\text{ $\mid$ }
\left(
  \frac{r_1}{m_1}
+ \frac{r_2}{m_2}
+ \frac{r_3}{m_3}
\right) 
\in
\mathbb{Z}
\end{align}

But this is too piece-meal for my tastes.

There must be some application of the Chinese remainder theorem that can tell me when:
\begin{equation}
  m_2 m_3 r_1
+ m_1 m_3 r_2
+ m_1 m_2 r_3
\equiv
0 
\text{ mod }
\text{ lcm}\left( m_1, m_2, m3 \right)
\end{equation}
does or does not admit a solution?

Can anyone point me to an article or text which discusses under what conditions the above congruence does or does not have solutions in the three variables: $\left(r_1, r_2, r_3\right)$?

Do I solve for the an unrestricted solution for $\left(r_1, r_2, r_3\right)$ and then see if the co-prime condition is met?  Or can I use the co-primality of the $r_i$'s to my advantage?